# How to manage large files in Git and GitLab

Tags: git, gitlab, git-submodules, large-files, git-lfs

I am working on a Django project that has 3 Large files.

- 1st file: 4.3 GB
- 2nd file: ~ 600 MB
- 3rd file: ~ 30 MB

**The Problem** is that Git can't handle large files and crashes. I used Git LFS to track the large files but the problem still exists, because if I push it to the GitLab repo, it exceeds the GitLab repo limit size(5 GB) or at least slows down the project.

What can I do?

Comment: Those 3 files are 4.93 GB total, so they don't exceed 5GB.

Comment: But with the project itself and other files, will exceed. And in future the project will grow.

Comment: Buy more space: https://about.gitlab.com/pricing/faq-paid-storage-transfer/ Or find a cheaper hosting. Or remove and stop tracking huge files in the repositories; store them somewhere else and copy to the destination directories outside of Git.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it needs more business decisions

Answer (score 1):

The answer is - do not track large binary files in GitLab. If it has a repo limit of 5GB, obviously you can't exceed it - so you have to lower the size of your file, or remove it from the repo.

Comment: Since the files are required for the project, is there any solution to store them anywhere else and use them normally?

Comment: I assume there are a myriad of solutions, but this is not a question that is answerable. It is a design decision ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

Use `.gitignore` to track unused dependencies that you should not use while pushing your code. You may find this helpful [list of gitignores](https://github.com/github/gitignore). Use one of these as per your project requirements.